# How to add seconds to Time in C#?

Tags: c#

How to add seconds to Time which is in **hours:min:sec** format in c#???

Example: I want to add seconds-5678 to **hours:min:sec** and then display the result...

Comment: Trivial question showing minimal effort at solving

Answer (score 20):

You can use [AddSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds.aspx), like

```
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5678)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("14:44:56", "HH:mm:ss", null);
string result = dt.AddSeconds(5678 ).ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // 16:19:34
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/pe6XJG)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try using TimeSpan struct

```
TimeSpan
.Parse("hours:min:sec")
.Add(TimeSpan FromSeconds(5678))
.ToString("c");
```