# Add the seconds to date to calculate Time

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time, seconds

Quick question, I've got this Program which gives me the seconds past since `01.01.2000`.

E.g. the Seconds for `12.02.2016 11:23:55` would roughly be `508590531` seconds.

Is there a Method that given the seconds past and the start date, that  calculates the end date?

I am aware that I could calculate the Minutes/Days/Months/Years that passed by hand, and then try to calculate the 'endTime' but I'd have to take care that I don't make a mistake by missing out a leap year for instance.

Quick Definition just to be totally clear:

```
Start Date : 01.01.2000
End Date:    Current Date
Time passed: Seconds passed between start date and end date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add seconds to Time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786276/how-to-add-seconds-to-time-in-c)

Comment: By the way, `508590531` seconds after `01.01.2000` midnight is `12.02.2016 11:08:51` not `12.02.2016 11:23:55`.

Comment: @Equalsk yeah that kinda sums up my question aswell :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. Just add the seconds, no magic or new solution required.

```
DateTime AddedFrom2000 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddSeconds(508590531);
```

Comment: Good answer, but also watch out for `DateTimeKind`.  If your original value was intended to be seconds past midnight 2000-01-01 **UTC**, then set `DateTimeKind.Utc` when creating the `DateTime` here.  As it sits, this code uses `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, which is fine if the basis really is a "floating time".  This distinction will matter if you use the resulting value in serialization or time zone conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

You can subtract to each other and use [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds) like;

```
var ts = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds);
```

If you wanna get it as an `int`, you can explicitly cast it as `(int)ts.TotalSeconds`.

If you *already* have seconds and you want to calculate based on your start date, you can use [`AddSeconds` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds) like;

```
var dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddSeconds(508590531); // {12.02.2016 11:08:51}
```

Comment: if I'M not mistaken, your code calculates the seconds past since 01.01.2000. What i am looking for is somehting like 01.01.2000 + seconds = Date

Comment: That's not what you're asking for,at least i understood same as @Soner

Answer (score 1):

```
var newDate = oldDate.AddSeconds(numSeconds);
```